# failed add intervention image at lumen 8

Tags: php, lumen

i have lumen 8 installed on my host. i want to add image editor with Intervention. i did these:

- run composer `require intervention/image` in my pc and get 4 folders. intervention, ralouphie, psr, guzzlehttp
- upload all generate files into vendor file
- in bootstrap/app.php i add these:

  `$app->register('Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider');   class_alias('Intervention\Image\Facades\Image', 'Image');`
- when i run my code i got this error `Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found`
- i have check folder and it have path like this.

  intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Facades
- based on app->register path, i did reupload file from Intervention folder

  Intervention/Image/Facades
- i run it again and still have same error message

i still new with this setup. and most tutorial i found is installing on laravel not lumen. need help where i miss or wrong in this steps. or is there any advice for retrieve scaleable image with lumen.

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

`$app->withFacades(true, [ 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' => 'Image', ]);`

`$app->register(Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class);`